# Print results in Qt widget iso console

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyside

I am porting my console app to a QT gui. The app get data from a website and prints the rsult line by line in the console ( I use spyder). Each line are a few strings.
Now I want to add a gui to the app so others can use the app as well. 
With QT designer I designed a nice gui. In a Main module I call the UI. Now I am trying to 'connect' my app to the gui. Since I am new to Qt (with PySide) I would like to build step by step and learn.
Now I would like to show ('print' line by line) the results in a widget (e.g. QListView).
Can you show me a example where ["this is line 1", "This is line two"] are show in two rows in a QT Widget.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `QTextBrowser` for a "logging" widget.

1. Just create a `QTextBrowser` widget in your main window (i.e. `self.log_widget = QTextBrowser()`)
2. Add it to some layout to be visible and part of the window
3. Log messages to it with the append method (which accepts a string). (i.e. `self.log_widget.append('Hello')`)

`QTextBrowser` is a powerful widget that can also accept HTML for formatted output.